# NotSerializableException GroupLayout sending Frame via RMI

Tags: java, jframe, rmi, serializable

I am sending a frame via RMI to another frame, for example:

```
public class FrameOne extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
   sendViaRMI(this);
}

public void sendViaRMI(FrameOne frameOne);
```

But then I get this exception:

```
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout
```

I tried to make FrameOne Serializable and I keep getting the same error.

I also tried to use transient in the other Frame (FrameTwo), that also didn't work.

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong -- your layout, the GroupLayout isn't serializable, and so this is preventing your object from being serialized.

A question and a possible solution: why try to serialize and send a JFrame? Instead why not send the model data or the changed model data, and let the other end recreate or modify its view accordingly?

Comment: @y451n: Please re-read my recommendations as I haven't recommended anything of the kind, nor do I recommend it. Again, serialize the model, the data, not the view (the GUI).

Comment: I would like to point out that some swing component models will add ModelListeners to themselves when they are rendered that are not serializable. Its bit me before, so watch out for that.